# MySQL return 'empty result' even with coalesce

Tags: mysql

I have some trouble with MySQL.

Here is the query I use:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(SUM(`a`.`battles`), 0) AS `battles`
FROM
    `account_stats` AS `a`
WHERE
    `a`.`account_id` = 12345
GROUP BY
    `a`.`account_id`
```

The Table `account_stats` is not empty, but has no row with `account_id = 12345`.

I want that MySQL returns **0 battles** instead of `Empty set`. But even with **COALSECE** or **IFNULL** it returns `Empty set`.

When I remove the `GROUP BY` everything works fine, but I need it to calculate the SUM of battles.

Is there a way to workaround this problem?

Comment: This is not what `GROUP BY` is for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want information on one account, you can use conditional aggregation if you want the query to return a row with the value of `0`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a.account_id = 12345 THEN a.battles ELSE 0 END) as battles
FROM account_stats a;
```

If the table is not empty, then you don't need `coalesce()`.

If you have an index on `account_id` and the table is big, the following would probably be more efficient because the subquery would use the index and the rest of the query would be manipulating a single row:

```
SELECT x.account_id, COALESCE(SUM(a.battles), 0) as battles
FROM (SELECT 12345 as account_id
     ) x LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.account_id, SUM(a.battles) as battles
      FROM account_stats a
      WHERE a.account_id = 12345
     ) a
     ON x.account_id = a.account_id;
```

Comment: Works great. But you need to add "a.account_id" in the SELECT of the second subquery.